# Scipy & Ipython Notebook: Package mangement tool?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `Ipython Notebook` that I'd like to share with others, and it uses a lot of packages.

I'm wondering if there is any tool for installing packages with ease? So others won't need to run `pip install` for each packages that I listed.

[image]

In `Ruby on Rails`, there is a `gemfile`, I can just run `bundle install` and then all gem are installed, which saves a lot of time.

I'm wondering if there is a `gemfile` and `bundle install` for `ipython notebook`? So we can install packages with ease.

Comment: `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` (w/ setuptools/distutils) are two idioms used to manage dependencies in python.

Comment: You could ask for a *requirements.txt* created with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in a virtualenv of choice, and then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#overview

Comment: @skywalker and now, I have made my ipython notebook, how can I generate a `reqirements.txt` with ease?

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` should do it (Linux or Mac). I'm not sure it will work on Windows though, try it. This is also assuming your with a newer version of pip.

Comment: For scientific applications conda is probably the best http://conda.pydata.org/docs/

Comment: @MikeMüller Agreed. See also: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `pip`:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You could distribute that with the notebook. Then to use it:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is the how to with *requirements.txt* [method](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files). But the basic workflow is above.

As a note the requirements file will look something like:

```
requests==2.8.1
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
stripe==1.27.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4
wheel==0.26.0
WTForms==1.0.5
```

Where you can see there are versions for each package. This method handles dependencies as well. So if one package depends on another, pip installs in such a way that there shouldn't be any errors. Though it might not always be the case.

This method should work in a Windows Powershell, definitely does in Mac and Linux.

Another is with `conda`:

```
conda create -n myenv python==3.5.0
```

This creates a conda environment. Which can be activated or deactivated. If activated you can install from a dependency file as:

```
conda env create -f requirements.yml
```

Similarly the requirements.txt can be created as:

```
conda env export > requirements.yml
```

Comment: Pip is a good choice for Mac / Unix development. One common task in production software deployments is to spin up a new server (or cluster), run some bootstrap commands to set up the environment, then run your processing code. Using the pip requirements file lets you programmatically install python libraries and you can include specific versions which is also important!

Comment: Your explaination is much simpler than the `conda`'s tutorial, it's just too long and not to the point. I think you can still add a screenshot about in `Anaconda`'s `Launcher` interface, where you can select and create `environment`

Comment: Additionally, 1. where can I see the full list of the new `env` created through `Launcher` interface? I didn't find any `.yml`. 2. How can I distribute my `env`? by sending the `.yml` with my code?

Comment: From the command line you can see all the environments you've created by  `conda env list`. This shows the names of the environments and paths to them. An `*` is placed next to the currently active environment. Sometimes doc's necessarily long-winded, there is something to be said about completeness after all. To activate use `source activate myenv`, similarly `source deactivate`. And yes, you could distribute your env with *.yml*

Comment: Just an update, the specific docs could be find at http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#share-an-environment

Answer (score 1):

For scientific applications [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) is probably the best option. It allows to install from a file of package names:

```
conda install --file file_with_package_names.txt
```

Furthermore, it offers virtual environments that are more powerful than the standard virtual env:

```
conda create -n my_new_env python=3.5
```

Activate this environment:

```
source conda activate my_new_env
```

Get help with:

```
conda -h
```

List all installed packages:

```
conda list
```

List all conda environments:

```
conda info -e
```

It offers much more and works on all major operating systems. All installs are binary. So no compilation of extensions. Makes Windows users very happy. But is great for Linux/Mac folks too.

[This](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html) is a nice comparison of `conda`,  `pip`, and `virtualenv`.

Comment: Just read it for a while, the tutorial is too long and not to the point. Quite disappointed.

Comment: Added a fee common commands.  Most important things on page page: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html